# GoogleScript GetBytes size limit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, byte

I made a script in GoogleScript what downloads video from GoogleDrive.

I'm using `DriveApp.GetFilesByID()` and `GetBytes()`.

With video <1mb it worked perfect but when i tried to download video >300mb it give me error File exceeds the maximum file size.

How can i avoid this limit?

Comment: If the DriveApp download is considered to be a fetch (which it may not), then it's 100 MB: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: I get error on DriveApp.getFileById(video.getId()).getAs("video/mp4").getBytes(); not on downloading.
So, limit is on GetBytes. This is so stupid, why i can't get bytes from a large file?

Comment: The `Blob` object which `getAs()` returns is described as a "data interchange object for Apps Script services". What are you intending to do with the file? Can you not use the `Blob` or do you specifically need the bytes?

Comment: I'm returning those bytes to Unity, and save as .mp4.
I didn't found another way to download file via Unity from GoogleDrive.
Also i found this page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#UrlFetch
Maybe if i will make a billing account it let me download larger file... but not sure if it will work with trial account

Comment: Drive has a proper API with support for .NET languages: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/drive/v2

Comment: To use Drive API you will need Auoth2.0. I don't want that, so i'm accessing Drive via GoogleScripts, what doesn't need Auoth2.0.
I will look through documentation again and hope to find something usefull.

Comment: Btw, i tried to download a 82mb file, still get error.
So, it's not a fetch with 100mb limit.